# Accessing elements inside dynamically created divs with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm quite new to javascript and JQuery programming. Usually, to access elements I give them an id, so I can get them like `$("#"+id).blabla().`

But now I need to dynamically create a div, and access elements inside it.

Something like

```
<div id="automaticallyGeneratedId">
   <div ???></div> <!-- first div -->
   <div ???></div> <!-- second div -->
</div>
```

What are the best practices to access and identify each of the inner divs? 
I generate another id for them? 
Or what?

I don't have the theory of selectors fully clear.

**edit**: modified the question from identifying a single inner div to identifying divs amongs many of them

Comment: I came across the same problem as you did in 2012. I have generated couple of html elements inside a loop and give them IDs like this id="element"+i, now I don't know how to access them? I tried the same way as you explained above in your question but that didn't work. What is the solution you adapt to get this thing worked? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can maintain a pattern when you're generating `id`. For example:

if you always generate `id` like: `myid1`, `myid2`,`myid3`...

```
<div id="myid1">
   <div></div>
</div>

<div id="myid2">
   <div></div>
</div>

......
```

then you can try:

```
$('div[id^=myid]').find('div').foo();
```

OR

```
$('div[id^=myid] div').foo();
```

Here, `^=` is start with selector, so `div[id^=myid]` will select `div` whose `id` start with `myid`.

You can also use Contain word selector which is `~=` and use like `$('div[id~=myid]')`. This will select `div` with `id` contains word `myid`.

Instead of `id` if you want to use other attribute eg. `name` then change selector like:

`$('div[name^=myid]')` or `$('div[name~=myid]')`.

Comment: your answer is interesting, but the question is slightly different: I need to assign "names" (ids?) and access a number of elements inside an outer div. Being inspired by your question, I think I could generate subids like div1, div1-1, div 1-2

Comment: @cdarwin that means, instead of `id` you need `name` attribute to container (outer) `div`? e.g `<div name="dynamicid"></div>` instead of `<div id="dynamicid"></div>`

Comment: it's not important assigning name or id to the outer div, what I meant is that I was interested in accessing the inner divs and not the outer one. I always used only "$(id)", but I see that find accepts the same selectors as $ does, so I understand that I can use your suggestion in the find part too, like $(...).find('div[id]'), right?

Answer (score 2):

It's usually a good practice that if you already have a reference to that outer div to just search from there using find.

You can give it an id, or if you want to use a more general approach you can use classes.

```
<div class="subdiv">...


$('#automaticallyGeneratedId').find('div.subdiv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you create them, you can assign event handlers and the likes straight on them. Like this:

```
var div = $( '<div></div>' );
div.on( 'click', function() {
    // Do something when the generated div is clicked
});

// Then, add it to the DOM
$( 'body' ).append( div );
```

You don't need to bother selecting them with ID or classes, they're already available in your code.

Another way is to use event bubbling to handle newly created elements of the same class. A good link about this is this one: http://beneverard.co.uk/blog/understanding-event-delegation/

Comment: I know, but what if later I need accessing a subdiv of that div? The question is about that

Answer (score 0):

Many ways you can create an element and give him an Id or Class, or use the DOM to access it..

```
$("html").prepend('<div id="foo"></div>');
$("#foo").doSomething();
```

another way

```
$("#automaticallyGeneratedId").find("div").doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the div in the element with the id:

```
$("#automaticallyGeneratedId div").whatever
```

Comment: I can have many divs inside the outer div, so I need an exact way to identify them

Answer (score 0):

If you cache the divs you could use something like:

```
var myDiv1Child = $('div', myDiv1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegated listener and within the listener you can find the element by doing this

```
//If a div inside the parent is clicked then execute the function within
$('.PARENT_CLASS').click("div", function(){
//This variable holds all the elements within the div
var rows = document.querySelector('.PARENT_CLASS').getElementsByTagName('div');
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(this);  //The element you wish to manipulate
    }
  }
});
```